# Where can I find some publicly available dataset for retail/grocery store companies?

Tags: data-request

I am looking for some publicly available dataset for retail/grocery store companies which (preferably) includes data about there stores, number of employees and operations. I tried to look around but couldn't find any dataset related to retail/grocery store companies. Does anyone know about such datasets that I can view and download(free or paid-any option)?

Answer (score 4):

The good folks at [Code4Huntsville*](https://twitter.com/code4huntsville) shared a dataset containing useful info about retails and grocery stores in their city, including geolocation, which makes it really interesting. It is available [here](http://codeforhuntsville.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/retail-grocery-stores).

- Code for Huntsville's twitter handle 404s (as of 2019-08-23), there is a [facebook link](https://www.facebook.com/groups/code4huntsville/) (but I can't see it without an account, not sure if its active), and they also have an [open data soft profile](https://codeforhuntsville.opendatasoft.com/page/aboutc4h/).

Comment: Thanks for the link but I am looking for a dataset which has information such as store size,number of employees and other operational details. The one you pointed has only location info. Also I am looking it for a retail store chain like walmart etc and not for separate individual stores like the one in the above dataset

Answer (score 0):

The quarterly and annual reports from these kinds of companies are publicly available. Here is [Walmart’s 2018 (2019 fiscal year)](http://www.corporatereport.com/walmart/2019/ar/walmart_financials.pdf) filing.

In it, you can find store count, geographic location. Their information on employees is a little sparse because of things like turnover, but other employee programs might be mentioned in similar 10k or annual financial reports.

Answer (score 0):

Kroger makes a lot of data available via their API:

https://developer.kroger.com/reference

This includes products, cart, customer identity, locations, chains, etc. for all stores associated with Kroger.

https://www.kroger.com/i/kroger-family-of-companies